# Php how to print array response in print_r

Tags: php

I got a response like this now i want to print

`[products]` how to print

i try this  **print_r($response['products']);**

**My Response**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [username] => admin
                    [firstName] => admin
                    [lastName] => admin


                    [products] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 1
                                    [url] => mytest.html
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 2
                                    [url] => mytest.html
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 3
                                    [url] => mytest.html
                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 4
                                    [url] => mytest.html
                                )

                            [4] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 5
                                    [url] => mytest.html
                                )

                            [5] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 6
                                    [url] => mytest.html
                                )

                            [6] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 7
                                    [url] => mytest.html
                                )

                        )
                )

        )

    [error] => 
    [errorMessage] => 
)
```

Comment: `$response->users[0]->products[0]->name` for example.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I don't want to foreach i used thease to some varibles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This one

```
print_r($response->users['0']->products);
```

Comment: i need to print all products

Comment: The above should print all the indexes from 0 to 6.
You can try foreach if you want each array to be shown one at a time like this:
============================================
   foreach($response->users['0']->products as $single_product):
    print_r($single_product);
  endforeach;

Comment: how to get only names

Comment: Names can be obtained this way :
=============================
foreach($response->users['0']->products as $single_product): echo $single_product['name']; endforeach;

Comment: in same way i want to all name not foreach

Comment: $name1=$response->users['0']->products['0']->name;
$name2=$response->users['0']->products['1']->name;
$name3=$response->users['0']->products['2']->name;
$name4=$response->users['0']->products['3']->name;
$name5=$response->users['0']->products['4']->name;
$name6=$response->users['0']->products['5']->name;
$name7=$response->users['0']->products['6']->name;